# XSL - check if attribute is equal to the selected value

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working with **xsl** file, which is used to create form fields. I need to check if the option value is the same as the selected value, and add selected attribute to that option field. This is the code for creating options (everything is working here, and options are created dynamically):

```
<xsl:when test="@type='select'">
                                <xsl:attribute name="title">Select List</xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="field_id" select="$field_id" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="field_type" select="@type" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="isEditing" select="$isEditing" />
                                </xsl:apply-templates>
                                <xsl:element name="div">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$field_id" /></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="type">select</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="class">field  ui-select</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:element name="select">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$field_id" /></xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$field_id" /></xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="data-native-menu">false</xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="size">1</xsl:attribute>

                                        <xsl:attribute name="required">
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="@required='required'">required</xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </xsl:attribute>

                                        <xsl:attribute name="onchange">CustomJS.manageDropdownSelect(this)</xsl:attribute>

                                        <xsl:attribute name="data-value">
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="@data-value!=''">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="@data-value" /></xsl:when>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </xsl:attribute>

                                        <xsl:for-each select="./options/option">
                                            <xsl:element name="option">

                                                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                </xsl:attribute>

                                                <xsl:value-of select="." />

                                                <xsl:if test="@data-value='@value'">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
                                                </xsl:if>

                                            </xsl:element>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:element>

                                <!-- field data -->
                                <xsl:element name="input">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="id">field_id</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="type">hidden</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="class">fielddata</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="concat($field_id,':',@type)" /></xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:when>
```

This is the part which adds **data-value**:

```
<xsl:attribute name="data-value">
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="@data-value!=''">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="@data-value" /></xsl:when>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
```

And this is the part which is responsible for the options:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./options/option">
    <xsl:element name="option">

                                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                        </xsl:attribute>

                                        <xsl:value-of select="." />

                                        <xsl:if test="@data-value='@value'">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>

                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:for-each>
```

I need to figure it out how to connect this section with the selected value:

```
 <xsl:if test="@data-value='@value'">
       <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:if>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT

Example of XML code I get:

```
<field type="select" name="" id="select_0" data-value="List 14" required="false">
    <options>
        <option>List 1</option>
        <option>List 12</option>
        <option>List 13</option>
        <option>List 14</option>
        <option>List 12</option>
        <option>List 125</option>
    </options>
</field>
```

Comment: Just to confirm... Are you saying the `<option>` tags are being created correctly, but the `selected` attribute is not actually appearing on any of them? Thanks!

Comment: Yep, all the options are created without any issue, and select is getting data-value properly (based on selected option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of your statements. Attributes must be created before any other child nodes of the element. As [per the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes)...

> The following are all errors:
>
> - Adding an attribute to an element after children have been added to it; implementations may either signal the error or ignore the
>     attribute.

`xsl:value-of` is createng a child text node, in your case.

Additionally, you had the attribute `@value` in apostrophes in your test, which would be looking for a literal string value of "@value". But in your case, you want to check the actual value of the node, which is a text node. So just use `text()`

Furthermore, `data-value` is an attribute on the ancestor `field` element, not the current `option` element. You should be doing `../../@data-value=text()` and not `@data-value='@value'`

So, your code should look like this:

```
<xsl:element name="option">
     <xsl:attribute name="value">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
     </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:if test="../../@data-value=text()">
        <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:element>
```

Note, there is no need to use `xsl:element` to create elements here, just write out the element directly. Your could can be simplified to the following:

```
<option value="{.}">
    <xsl:if test="../../@data-value=text()">
        <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</option>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) to create the `value` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for detail answer :). This is still refusing to work (I tried both examples), but I now have a starting point where to look :).

Comment: I have just made some edits to my answer, if you want to take another look.

Comment: I added the example of XML code which is created. Oddly, options don't have value attribute, but HTML is having. This is supposed to be this way?

Comment: I just spotted another issue around `data-value` which I have added to my answer.

Comment: Well this is still refusing to work :/, and I think I hit the wall for today. Thanks a lot for your helping me, don't want to bother you anymore with this :).

Comment: No problems! I just spotted another issue! You should be using `text()` here to test the text value of the element, not `@value`

Comment: I own you a beer :). You rock mate. Thanks a lot :)